# aws elastic load balancer gives me an ip that doesn't work?

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, dig

i have configured route 53 & classic elb into some ec2 instances running nginx / puma.

even with one instance i get two ip's in my dig output, one of which does not work.

```
sig :: ~ 7 » dig  wtf.com             

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> wtf.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43286
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wtf.com.            IN    A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wtf.com.        60    IN    A    52.31.xxx.xxx
wtf.com.        60    IN    A    54.229.wtf.wtf

;; Query time: 23 msec
;; SERVER: x.x.x.x#53(x.x.x.x)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan 10 12:03:37 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60
```

could anyone shed any light on why i might be getting the weird ip or how to get rid of it or make it work?

many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

there were unhealthy availability zones configured in my elb instance.

Comment: Can you explain how you discovered this?

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  It would help others who encounter a similar problem if you could elaborate a little.